# Recording Smallest-So-Far Values in NumPy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a NumPy array like:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 5, 4, 2, 3, 6, 7, 5, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, 4, 2, 8, 3, 5, 9, 2, 3, 4])
```

And starting at `i = 9`, I want to traverse each element toward `i = 0` and then to record the "smallest-so-far" numbers along the way along with the index of those numbers. In this example:

```
left_val = []
left_idx = []
min_so_far = np.inf
for i in range(9, -1, -1):
    if x[i] < min_so_far:
        left_val.append(x[i])
        left_idx.append(i)
        min_so_far = x[i]
```

The left min-so-far values are `[5, 3, 2, 1]` and they are located at indices `[7, 4, 3, 0]`.

You can also traverse toward the right:

```
right_val = []
right_idx = []
min_so_far = np.inf
for i in range(9, x.shape[0]):
    if x[i] < min_so_far:
        right_val.append(x[i])
        right_idx.append(i)
        min_so_far = x[i]
```

The right min-so-far values are `[4, 2]` and they are located at index `[11, 12]`

Is there a faster way to do this `min_so_far` search when the length of `x` is much larger?

Comment: Can you clarify what your expected output would be? Because your current gets a single value and its index, but your explanation seems to imply several values being in the output.

Comment: I've added the output produced by both algorithms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def right_mins(x):
    # To avoid leading infs, truncate some more
    start = np.argmax(np.isfinite(x))
    y = np.minimum.accumulate(x[start:])
    idx = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(y)) + 1] + start
    return x[idx], idx

def left_mins(x):
    y, idx = right_mins(x[::-1])
    return y, x.size - 1 - idx
```

You can apply these functions directly to the slices that you want, e.g.:

```
>>> left_mins(x[:10])
(array([5., 3., 2., 1.]), array([7, 4, 3, 0]))
>>> n, i = right_mins(x[9:])
>>> n, i + 9
(array([4., 2.]), array([11, 12]))
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but `left_mins(x)` appears to only return `(array([1.]), array([0]))` when I supply the same `x` as in the question. Instead, `left_mins` needs to return `(array([5, 3, 2, 1]), array([7, 4, 3, 0]))`.

Comment: @slaw The functions need to be applied to the relevant section of the array.  `right_mins( [x[:10] )` and `left_mins( [ x[10:] )`.  Both then need the inf values and corresponding indices removing.  np.inf is the min when it's first found.

Comment: @slaw. I've added a couple of examples showing how to run your exact use-cases. If you want to subset the array, you need to add the offset of the leftmost index to the result

Comment: @slaw. Do you have a particular usecase for the edit you suggested? Let's discuss before you modify the code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I had provided a comment for the edit but this suggested change is pertinent to the original inputs. Due to the presence of `np.inf` in the data, I am receiving a `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  a = op(a[slice1], a[slice2])` warning due to `np.diff(y)` not knowing how to handle the subtraction when `np.inf` is involved. Thus, I convert all `np.inf` values in `y` to `np.nan` to avoid this warning altogether. The result is still the same but the warning is suppressed.

Comment: @slaw. Setting elements to `nan` is just plain wrong in this case. Look at the result you get: it's nonsense because `x > nan` is always false. You have two options: treat the infinities as a special case (truncate the array), or just accept the warning.

Comment: @slaw. See the updated solution. I just slice off the leading infinities and go to town

Comment: @slaw. OK. Now it works! Thanks for catching the warning. It actually makes the code more compact to preempt it.

Comment: `idx = np.insert(y[1:] != y[:-1], 0, True)` and `return x[idx], np.where(idx)[0]` also an option to avoid `>` comparisons which might not be well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite what you want, but it'll give you minima for all sublists as you traverse the array. It's pythonic but it'll be slow for reasonably sized numpy arrays.

```
right_going = [min(x[n:i]) for i in range(n, len (x))]
left_going = [min(x[(n-i):n]) for i in range(n)]
```

the array index at which values are minima is then `n + list_index` in the first case and just the index of the list in the second case. You could then do exactly what you want by getting the indices and values of the first (or last) occurrence of repeat values in these lists.

Comment: Pythonic maybe, but certainly not numpythonic

Comment: @MadPhysicist, given the sequential nature of this problem, "numpythonic" (ugg!) may not be possible.  `np.minimum.accumulate` gets the minimum of various ranges, but I don't think there's an `accumulate` version of `argmin`.

Comment: @hpaulj. I've posted an answer with a pretty vectorized solution. Sure there's no argmin.accumulate, but the usual diff trick works just fine after minimum.accumulate